# Excel VBA eaching data in different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code that should take value form activecell in sheet1 and look for this value in column A:A in sheet2. When it finds it, code should input data into the cell to the right (still in sheet2). It should input data from txtform (which is data written by user into form textbox.

```
Private Sub BtnOK_Click()
 For Each element In Sheets("sheet2").Range("A:A")
    If element.Value = ActiveCell Then
    element.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtform
    Exit For
   End If
 Next
Unload Me

End Sub
```

It doesn't work. Runtime error 1004. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of possible reasons:

- Vou are selecting a different cell (element.Select), thereby changing ActiveCell
- You are comparing a value (element.value) to an object (ActiveCell); change to ActiveCell.Value
- I am assuming txtform is a VBA variable (e.g. a String) declared somewhere above. If not, declare it in a variable or reference the object property.

.

```
Private Sub BtnOK_Click()
    For Each element In Sheets("sheet2").Range("A:A")
        If element.Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
            element.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtform
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Unload Me
End Sub
```